# How to make a DIV scroll to its own bottom?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created the following chat box:

[image]

I've set overflow-auto to the div.

But newer messages apear at the bottom of the div. How can I set the scrollbar to the bottom, but only for this div? (I don't want to scroll into view the chat box.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scrollTo` function on the div and scroll it to: `scrollHeight` minus `clientHeight`.

See MDN:

- [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)
- [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)
- [scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo)

**Example:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rLvqy4u/)

Comment: thanks! i'll give you the check once the 2 mins have completed :)

Comment: thx :D You're welcome!